# Не проходит валидация массива Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Всем привет, подскажите пожалуйста как мне сделать валидацию у $items?

Есть такая валидация

```html
public function rules(): array
    {

        $items = [];

        foreach ($this->category->allAttributes() as $attribute) {
            $rules = [
                $attribute->required ? 'required' : 'nullable',
            ];
            if ($attribute->isInteger()) {
                $rules[] = 'integer';
            } elseif ($attribute->isFloat()) {
                $rules[] = 'numeric';
            } else {
                $rules[] = 'string';
                $rules[] = 'max:255';
            }
            if ($attribute->isSelect()) {
                $rules[] = Rule::in($attribute->variants);
            }

            $items['attribute.' . $attribute->id] = $rules;
        }


        return array_merge([
            'title' => 'required|string',
            'content' => 'required|string',
            'price' => 'required|integer',
            'address' => 'required|string',
        ], $items);

    }
```

вот что ддешит return array_merge

```html
array:12 [▼
  "title" => "required|string"
  "content" => "required|string"
  "price" => "required|integer"
  "address" => "required|string"
  "attribute.29" => array:3 [▼
    0 => "required"
    1 => "string"
    2 => "max:255"
  ]
  "attribute.30" => array:4 [▼
    0 => "nullable"
    1 => "string"
    2 => "max:255"
    3 => In {#618 ▶}
  ]
  "attribute.31" => array:3 [▼
    0 => "nullable"
    1 => "integer"
    2 => In {#619 ▶}
  ]
  "attribute.32" => array:4 [▼
    0 => "nullable"
    1 => "string"
    2 => "max:255"
    3 => In {#620 ▶}
  ]
  "attribute.33" => array:4 [▼
    0 => "nullable"
    1 => "string"
    2 => "max:255"
    3 => In {#621 ▶}
  ]
  "attribute.34" => array:4 [▼
    0 => "nullable"
    1 => "string"
    2 => "max:255"
    3 => In {#793 ▶}
  ]
  "attribute.35" => array:4 [▼
    0 => "nullable"
    1 => "string"
    2 => "max:255"
    3 => In {#722 ▶}
  ]
  "attribute.40" => array:4 [▼
    0 => "nullable"
    1 => "string"
    2 => "max:255"
    3 => In {#687 ▶}
  ]
]
```

То есть сейчас у меня валидация работает на

```html
'title' => 'required|string',
'content' => 'required|string',
'price' => 'required|integer',
'address' => 'required|string',
```

а вот $items никак не валидируется... сейчас например установлено первому атрибуту обязательное поле.. но при отправке запроса редиректит обратно на форму

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```html
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
    @include('cabinet.adverts._nav')

    <form method="POST" action="{{ route('cabinet.adverts.create.advert.store', [$category, $region]) }}">
        @csrf

        <div class="card mb-3">
            <div class="card-header">
                Создание объявления
            </div>
            <div class="card-body pb-2">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="title" class="col-form-label">Заголовок</label>
                            <input id="title" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('title') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="title" value="{{ old('title') }}" required>
                            @if ($errors->has('title'))
                                <span class="invalid-feedback"><strong>{{ $errors->first('title') }}</strong></span>
                            @endif
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="price" class="col-form-label">Цена</label>
                            <input id="price" type="number" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('price') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="price" value="{{ old('price') }}" required>
                            @if ($errors->has('price'))
                                <span class="invalid-feedback"><strong>{{ $errors->first('price') }}</strong></span>
                            @endif
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="address" class="col-form-label">Адрес</label>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-11">
                            <input id="address" type="text" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('address') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="address" value="{{ old('address', $region->getAddress()) }}" required>
                            @if ($errors->has('address'))
                                <span class="invalid-feedback"><strong>{{ $errors->first('address') }}</strong></span>
                            @endif
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-1">
                            <span class="btn btn-primary btn-block location-button" data-target="#address"><span class="fa fa-location-arrow"></span></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="content" class="col-form-label">Описание объявления</label>
                    <textarea id="content" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('content') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="content" rows="10" required>{{ old('content') }}</textarea>
                    @if ($errors->has('content'))
                        <span class="invalid-feedback"><strong>{{ $errors->first('content') }}</strong></span>
                    @endif
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="card mb-3">
            <div class="card-header">
                Характеристики
            </div>
            <div class="card-body pb-2">
                @foreach ($category->allAttributes() as $attribute)

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for=attribute_{{ $attribute->id }}" class="col-form-label">{{ $attribute->name }}</label>

                        @if ($attribute->isSelect())

                            <select id="attribute_{{ $attribute->id }}" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('attributes.' . $attribute->id) ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="attributes[{{ $attribute->id }}]">
                                <option value=""></option>
                                @foreach ($attribute->variants as $variant)
                                    <option value="{{ $variant }}"{{ $variant == old('attributes.' . $attribute->id) ? ' selected' : '' }}>
                                        {{ $variant }}
                                    </option>
                                @endforeach
                            </select>

                        @elseif ($attribute->isNumber())

                            <input id="attribute_{{ $attribute->id }}" type="number" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('attributes.' . $attribute->id) ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="attributes[{{ $attribute->id }}]" value="{{ old('attributes.' . $attribute->id) }}">

                        @else

                            <input id="attribute_{{ $attribute->id }}" type="text" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('attributes.' . $attribute->id) ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="attributes[{{ $attribute->id }}]" value="{{ old('attributes.' . $attribute->id) }}">

                        @endif

                        @if ($errors->has('parent'))
                            <span class="invalid-feedback"><strong>{{ $errors->first('attributes.' . $attribute->id) }}</strong></span>
                        @endif
                    </div>

                @endforeach
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Создать</button>
        </div>
    </form>

@endsection
```

Comment: Если происходит редирект обратно на форму, то какие-то из полей не проходят валидацию. Сделайте вывод ошибок валидации формы и добавьте в вопрос, пожалуйста, массив валидируемых данных: не совсем понятно, что есть на входе при валидации.

Comment: @РустамГимранов валидация не проходит из затого что стоит обязательное поле для заполнения required у одного из атрибутов.. Если я уберу что данный пункт обязателен к заполеннию то все проходит все ок.. Но сейчас даже если это обязательное поле заполнено то оно все равно не проходит валидацию.. редиректит обратно на форму.. как то надо сделать проверку что если поле обязательное и если оно не заполнено то выходило сообщение об ошибке заполните обязательное поле

http://i.imgur.com/6LQK5XQ.png

Добавил видео короткое с проблемой
https://cloud.mail.ru/public/3A1m/2MVhX8PZZ

Comment: Ну так же переменная `$errors` доступна во всех [шаблонах-вьюшках](https://laravel.com/docs/master/validation#working-with-error-messages).

Comment: @РустамГимранов во вьюшках прописаны $errors.. но у дополнительных атрибутов ничего не выводится к сожалению.. прикрепил вьюшку в главный пост

Comment: Вы не поверите, но тут `$items['attribute.' . $attribute->id] = $rules;` не хватает буквы **s** `attributes`

Comment: блин жестоко) спасибо большое!!! а как теперь текст добавить? чтобы было написано не заполенно поле, сейчас оно просто красным подсвечивается

Comment: Могу только предположить `$errors->first('attributes.' . $attribute->id)` по аналогии c `$errors->has('attributes.' . $attribute->id)`

Comment: @РустамГимранов добавил first вместо has но результат не изменился..

http://i.imgur.com/wcz44TE.png